# UML and favourite IDE

Tags: c#, java, c++, ide, uml

I've just downloaded Visual Paradigm for UML and it looks quite ok. Does anyone have any experience with it? Or maybe someone has his own favourite IDE which is worth using and wouldn't mind sharing this knowledge? Do not want to use IDE which is written in JAVA or C# for patriotic reasons.

Comment: Visual Studio, then. It's written in C++

Comment: I think Visual Paradigm is written in Java. At least there are a lot of .jar files there ;)

Comment: @Joel Few corrections: Visual Studio (2010) is written in C#  and another even more important thing is that they do not support many of UML constructs. So no VS definitely not.

Comment: VS2010 is written in C++, only the UI is done in C#.

Comment: @DeadMG if that's so (suppose I believe you) why is there so much fuss and complaints about C++ and how difficult it is to write windows apps in it, when as according to you one can make UI in C# (which is as easy as women) and core in C++? Could you explain that to me please?

Comment: @There: What on earth are you talking about? People complain about C++ because it's a hard language, not for any valid reason. Besides, the core of VS was written in C++ a long, long time ago, well before C# or WPF were viable or even conceived of. And you're talking about Microsoft here, not some hobbyist developer, they can handle a hard language.

Comment: @DeadMG what I'm talking about is that everyone (almost) is complaining about the difficulties which you have when developing windows apps in C++. And that was (in my opinion) one of the reasons why VS2010 is developed in C# (at least GUI) and few others main softwares (AutoCAD for example) which were originally written in C or C++ and now they're switching to C# for the reason that it is much much easier to develop software in C# than in C++ and with todays computer's speed there is acceptable performance from this code. That's why even though Microsoft can handle hard language...

Comment: they've decided that it will be much more effective to do it in c# not in c++. And I'm not sure if you know but they are even going to rewrite compiler in c#. Reason - easiness of writing, easiness of maintanability etc. if compared to code written in C++. And do not get me wrong - I love C++ but seeing more and more software (serious companies - Microsoft, Autodesk et al) being developed instead of in C++ are developed in C# my prediction is that C++ will be adventually used mainly in embedded and real time apps. And I feel very bad about it because I see Java or Java from Microsoft...

Comment: as languages that are dumb down in order to be available to masses which wouldn't be able to program effectively in "hard" languages like C++ or C. And I agree with what you've said that C# is for hobbyist developers not for real pros. But it is not the place and time to discuss this subject in here.

Comment: @There: So what's the problem, here? Software is software, unless you want to write plugins or addons then who cares what language it's written in?

Comment: @DeadMG the problem is that thanks to C# IntelliSense reaction time instead of being counted in miliseconds is counted in seconds now. That's the problem.

Comment: @DeadMG so can I actually have UI made in c# and core in C++? And if yes how?

Comment: @There: It's called C++/CLI and P/Invoke.

Comment: @DeadMG neither of them are C++ (and by C++ I mean C++ developed by Bjarne) so what's your point? Are you still saying that Visual Studio 2010 has only UI in C# and core in C++ (the C++ developed by Bjarne)?

Comment: @There: So what? C++ developed by Bjarne is not the solution to all problems, ever. If all programs were written in Standard C++ and only Standard C++, we'd never write programs capable of anything except console IO. You're just being religious about it and not practical, which is that other languages have their uses and C++ actually sucks for a number of tasks.

Comment: @DeadMG the point I was making is that you've tried to say something that wasn't true  (your first comment: "VS2010 is written in C++, only the UI is done in C#.") and I just had to correct you for the reason that I do not like when people talk rubbish as you did.

Comment: @There: It is written in C++. There is nothing wrong with what I said. Visual Studio just happens to also use things that are not in the incredibly small subset of actual C++ that was personally specified by Bjarne Stroustrup.

Comment: @DeadMG no it is not written in C++. Is written in managed version of C++ developed by Microsoft. If you would say that it is written in managed ver. of C++ I wouldn't object but you've said that it is written in C++ which is first not true and second if you ask anyone (from the right circle) what do they understand by C++ 100% will answer that C++ means C++ invented by Bjarne. Except one person of course - you, for whom C++ and managed C++ are the same and in everyday talk you use those terms interchangebly. But it just isn't true.

Comment: It is almost as if I would talk about Java and C# in the same manner you talk C++ and managed ver of C++. They look the same they work similiar so what's the difference? One is called Java and another one Java from Microsoft but according to your approach it doesn't make real difference. Well, you are PLAIN WRONG.

Comment: @There: I think you'll find that managed C++ is a dialect of C++ just like every other implementation, and secondly, managed C++ is just used as the bridge between native C++ and the managed GUI. I said that the core of VS was written in C++, and that they used C++/CLI, not that the core of VS was written in C++/CLI. It isn't. It's written in native C++ and interropped with .NET via C++/CLI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend you Visual Paradigm. It is has very intuitive interface and it is easy to use. I use it at the moment. But if you want to try something else this page could be helpful http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UML_programs.

Answer (score 0):

The best modeling tool for Eclipse is Omondo.

It is just magic but also **so expensive** !!